# How do i receive HTML page as response from API using retrofit in Android?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

API is sending one HTML page as response.
[image: postment image]

Currently i am receiving as ResponseBody

```
public interface DashBoardHtmlJsonAPI {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/MobileDashbord")
    Call<ResponseBody> getHtml(@Field("UserName") String username, @Field("Password") String password);
}
```

I want convert the responseBody to String and load the html to webview.

```
html  = response.body().string();
```

After successful response above code return a blank string

I am not able to retrieve the html page as string.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()).build();
        DashBoardHtmlJsonAPI dashBoardHtmlJsonAPI = retrofit.create(DashBoardHtmlJsonAPI.class);
        Call<ResponseBody> call = dashBoardHtmlJsonAPI.getHtml(userName,password);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    String html="";
                    try {
                      html  = response.body().string();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    loadWebView(html);
                    Log.i("WEBVIEW",response.toString());
                    Log.i("WEBVIEW",html);


                }
                else {
                    Log.i("WEBVIEW",response.body().toString());

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("WEBVIEW",t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });
```

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: I would use OkHttp directly, rather than making the request through Retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the content from body

```
try {
   html  = response.body().content();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```